# Error trying to run composer with Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php

I am new to Laravel and to using the terminal.

I installed composer globally and it is running, but when I try to mv I get an error:

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

No such file or directory
```

I echo $PATH and get this:

```
/Users/ebernal/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin:/Users/ebernal/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-          
p286@global/bin:/Users/ebernal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-   
p286/bin:/Users/ebernal/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Not sure what all this means, and why can't Terminal not find /usr/local/bin?

I can run composer using composer.phar and it mostly runs, but at the very end I get this error:

```
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an    
error                      
[RuntimeException]  
Error Output:
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the error message, `no such file or directory`.

Locate the /usr/local/bin/composer file. Show hidden folders or use the `cd` command to navigate through Terminal.

You possibly don't have a composer folder, hence why it can't move it into it.